# Hii I am trying to bind datatable with ajax get request but I am not able to do that

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to bind data to jquery datatable with ajax get request but in success function of ajax get request I am getting error as Refrence error data is not defined

Below I have provided details about what I have tried

Below is the controller code :-

```
 public ActionResult BindBrand()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetBrand()
        {
            var finalResult = Common.GetProductBrand("1001");
            var JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalResult);
            var brandList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<GlobalCodes>>(JSONString);

            return Json(brandList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

and below is code in Mvc view

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetBrand", "Product")',
            //dataType: "json",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                var a = response.brandList;


            }
    });
    });



    function BindBrand(msg) {

        debugger;


        var properties = {
            bProcessing: true,
            bDestroy: true,
            bSort: true,
            data: msg,
            aoColumns: [
                { mData: 'GlobalCodeName' },
                {
                    mData: "",
                    bSortable: true,
                    mRender: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        //return "<i class=\"fa fa-pencil-square-o\" aria-hidden=\"true\" name=\"id_'" + rowObject.GlobalCodeID + "'\"   title=\"Update\"  onclick=\"UpdateBrand('" + rowObject.Inv_MainID + "')\"></i><i class=far fa-check-square></i>";
                        return '<i id="DocumentsTemplateID' + rowObject.GlobalCodeID + '" onclick="EditDocumentDetail1(' + rowObject.GlobalCodeID + ');" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" title="Edit Document"></i> <i onclick="SaveCheckboxvalue();" class="far fa-check-square"></i> ';

                    }
                }

            ]
        };
        var table = $('#tblBrand').DataTable(properties);


    }
</script>
```

I expect that on success function of ajax get request I should get list of returned json data of brandlist but I am facing error as Refrence error data is not defined

Comment: can you put the result of get URL/Product/GetBrand?

Comment: when you are BindBrand(msg) function calling?

Comment: I have found the answer by myself which is written below I changed this line in controller  return Json(new { brandList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  and in view I have changed   success: function (result) {
    debugger;

    var data = result.brandList;
    BindBrand(data);

   }
 });
 });